# How to find person Interest in any patent

Tags: practicality, us4737638

In reference to the patent: [US4737638](https://www.google.com/patents/US4737638)

How can I find out how many people have requested copies of this patent? I would like to contact them to determine if there is market interest in this method of isotope purification.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for asking an interesting question.

In general there is no particular or specific way to know who has downloaded or accessed patent. I really don't have clear idea if any log is kept for download counter but that would be a number itself not person specific.

If a certified copy of patent is asked from patent office then definitely one can get this information from patent office. I guess it would be limited and most of the time such copies are taken only by applicant itself.

To a further extent I feel one can find out through indirect correlation that who else is interested or in same filed by using Citation search like in this patent you can open it in [Espacenet](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?CC=US&NR=4737638A&KC=A&FT=D) and check forward citation [1](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/citingDocuments?CC=US&NR=4737638A&KC=A&FT=D&ND=&date=19880412&DB=&&locale=en_EP),  [2](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/citingDocuments?CC=US&NR=5086225A&KC=A&FT=D&ND=3&date=19920204&DB=&locale=en_EP),  [3](http://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/citingDocuments?CC=US&NR=6432174B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=4&date=20020813&DB=&locale=en_EP)  which will guide you to persons or atleast give you a way to dig more information.